# list values in Outlook Mail

Tags: python, html, list, email, outlook

Im just trying to automate an outlook mail with python. Im struggling a bit with a probably very small issue but still cannot find a solution so far.

I actually just want to display my listvalues in this html formatted emailbody as a normal list. That means vertically with linebreak - lika an enumeration.

The list can be dynamic. So there can be also more than 4 list_values.
This is my code so far. Is there anybody who can help me with an approach/solution.
Thanks in advance
Best regards
Sascha

```
import win32com.client as win32
list = ["dog","cat","mouse","monkey"]
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To =  "me@test.com"
mail.CC = "me@test.com"
mail.Subject = f'Test'
mail.HTMLBody = f"<p>This is my test_list:</p><br>"

mail.Display()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the items of the list with a [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) (*line break*) element :

```
import win32com.client as win32

a_list = ["dog", "cat", "mouse", "monkey"]

outlook = win32.Dispatch("outlook.application")
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = "me@test.com"
mail.CC = "me@test.com"
mail.Subject = 'Test'

mail.HTMLBody = f"<p>This is my test_list:<br>{'<br>'.join(a_list)}</p>"

mail.Display()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Thats exactly what i was looking for. Best regards, Sascha